# AlertView is running but not showing for didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, push-notification

using the debugger I've ensured `[alertView show];` is being called, but the dialog is not viewable, what else do I need to do to get it to show?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if( [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] != NULL)
    {
        NSString *msg = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
        if(msg != nil) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Usage Alert"
            message:msg  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you declare your view controller a `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`?

Comment: no I didn't .. I guess it could be any controller, it could even be a tab bar or a navbar... so I don't see how I'm supposed to do that?

Comment: Ok, I'll explain below....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, this turned out to be an issue with my compiler/xCode not actually recognizing the code I had put in or something along those lines, the environment was broken.

Answer (score 2):

In your view controller .h file, you need to declare the `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` Like this, before the opening curly braces, encapsulated with greater than and less than symbols:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourViewControllersName : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {

   // your variable declarations are here...
}

 // your method declarations are here...
```

Comment: For some reason the application state isn't active, when this method is called, it's very weird because the App is already running before receiving notification